# Errors using python magic when filtering large numbers of files based on MIME type

Tags: python, file, libmagic

I have a set of files in a directory and I'm making use of python-magic library to filter out files that are of type "text/plain" and remove all the non 'text/plain' files. Below is the code I'm using

```
import os
import magic
def ftype(path):
    fpath = path
    mime = magic.Magic(mime=True)
    for root, dirs, fnames in os.walk(path):
        for fname in fnames:
                mi = mime.from_file(fpath+'\\'+fname)
                if not mi.endswith('plain'):
                    os.remove(fpath + '\\' + fname)
                    print(fname)
                else:
                    pass

ftype('filepath')
```

I'm able to run the script successfully on a small set of files. However when I ran the script on a directory that had about 40000 files I get the below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dmg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py", line 91, in from_file
    return self._handle509Bug(e)
  File "C:\Users\dmg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py", line 100, in _handle509Bug
    raise e
  File "C:\Users\dmg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py", line 89, in from_file
    return maybe_decode(magic_file(self.cookie, filename))
  File "C:\Users\dmg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py", line 255, in magic_file
    return _magic_file(cookie, coerce_filename(filename))
  File "C:\Users\dmg\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\magic\magic.py", line 196, in errorcheck_null
    raise MagicException(err)
magic.magic.MagicException: b"line I64u: regex error 14 for `^[[:space:]]*class[[:space:]]+[[:digit:][:alpha:]:_]+[[:space:]]*\\{(.*[\n]*)*\\}(;)?$', (failed to get memory)"
```

I'm not sure what is the issue. Can someone help me with this or if there are any alternative approaches to do the above stated operation.

Update : Issue still exists after trying out some methods stated in the below comments.

Comment: Unrelated to the `MagicException` memory issue, it looks like the `else` after the outer `for` loop is redundant, and also `os.remove(fpath+'\\'+fname)` will run regardless of the MIME (the line is in the `if` and the `else` block). Is this intended?

Comment: Yes the else in the outer for loop isn't required as you've stated. I've edited my question. Yes I 'm still not sure about the other line as I tried commenting out the os.remove line and just printed out filenames instead and I get the same error. I'm quite new to python so not really sure whats wrong

Comment: OK. So it seems the issue lies in magic not being able to allocate memory, which could be caused by it (or the system) running out of memory. Are the files big? Are you running out of memory on your system?

Comment: Yes your right and I think the library could not allocate memory since the filesize is big. I tested this on about 47000 files which are a total of 444MB but I did not run out of memory on my system. If this doesn't work i'm looking for some alternative ways to achieve this.

Comment: Yes, the error seems to come from a regex library trying to allocate memory. You could try only running magic on the start of the file, for example (slightly modified from the docs, you may want to use a context manager): `mime.from_buffer(open(fpath+'\\'+fname).read(4096))`. You'll want to tune that number to ensure that you get an accurate result.

Comment: Thank you for the comment and I would try running this and let know.

Comment: I tried tuning in some number but I always get the error `return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 51: character maps to <undefined> ` . Also one other thing I noticed in my previous approach is I get the memory exception after 50 files. So the first 50 filenames gets printed but later I get the memory issue. I tried another scenario with just 50 files to make sure but only first 15 files gets displayed. So I guess it has to do something with the type.

Comment: Well the different error could indicate progress is being made. With different files (and thus different file sizes) it would be expected for the memory error to occur and different points. As for the `UnicodeDecodeError`, it looks like you'll need to open the file in binary mode (as there seems to be non-text data), so try specifying `'rb'` as a second argument to `open` (`open(fpath+'\\'+fname, 'rb')`). Browsing the source of python-magic it looks like the library encoded the data in `utf-8` again anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217650/discussion-between-dmorgan-and-xavc).